# SpringMVC & Hibernate : CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction;

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up and *Spring MVC + Hibernate* project but it's driving me nuts. I would also take in account suggestions to order the xml config files.

I have the following files:

- `web.xml`

  ```
  <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

      <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
      <context-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
      <listener>
          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

      <!-- Processes application requests -->
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
  ```
- `servlet-context.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


      <context:annotation-config />

      <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

      <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
      <annotation-driven />
      <tx:annotation-driven/>

      <context:component-scan base-package="es.landesoft.mvctesting" />
      <context:component-scan base-package="es.landesoft.mvctesting.service" />
      <context:component-scan base-package="es.landesoft.mvctesting.dao" />

      <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
      <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

      <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
          <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      </beans:bean>

          <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
         username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
        <beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
          <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
          <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=MyHome;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;"/>       
          <beans:property name="username" value="sa"/>
          <beans:property name="password" value="sarednal1"/>
          <beans:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>

        </beans:bean>


        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
          <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
          <beans:property name="configLocation">
              <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
          </beans:property>     
          <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="es.landesoft.mvctesting" />
          <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
              <beans:props>
                  <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</beans:prop>
                  <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
              </beans:props> 
          </beans:property>
          </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
          <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
          <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
      </beans:bean>
  ```
- `PersonController.java`

  ```
    package es.landesoft.mvctesting;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Locale;
  import javax.validation.Valid;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.ui.Model;
  import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

  import es.landesoft.mvctesting.JavaBeans.Person;
  import es.landesoft.mvctesting.service.PersonService;

  /**
   * Handles requests for the application home page.
   */
  @Controller
  public class PersonController {

      //private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);
      @Autowired
      private PersonService personService;        

      @RequestMapping(value = "/person/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
      @ResponseBody 
      public List<Person> getPersonJson() {               

          return personService.listPerson();    
      }

  }
  ```
- `PersonDAO.java`

  package es.landesoft.mvctesting.dao;

  ```
  import java.util.List;

  import es.landesoft.mvctesting.JavaBeans.Person;

  public interface PersonDAO {

      public void addContact(Person person);
      public List<Person> listPersons();
      public void removePerson(Integer id);
  }
  ```
- `PersonDaoClass.java`

  ```
  package es.landesoft.mvctesting.dao;

  import java.util.List;

  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

  import es.landesoft.mvctesting.JavaBeans.Person;

  @Repository
  public class PersonDaoClass implements PersonDAO {

      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      @Transactional
      @Override
      public void addContact(Person person) {

          sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(person);

      }

      @Transactional
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public List<Person> listPersons() {

          return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                  .createQuery("From Person").list();
      }

      @Transactional
      public void removePerson(Integer id) {

          Person person = (Person) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Person.class, id);
          if (person != null)
          {
              sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(person);          
          }

      }

  }
  ```
- `PersonService.java`

  ```
  package es.landesoft.mvctesting.service;

  import java.util.List;

  import es.landesoft.mvctesting.JavaBeans.Person;

      public interface PersonService {

          public void addContact(Person person);
          public List<Person> listPerson();
          public void removePerson(Integer id);
      }
  ```
- `PersonService.java`

  ```
      package es.landesoft.mvctesting.service;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

  import es.landesoft.mvctesting.JavaBeans.Person;
  import es.landesoft.mvctesting.dao.PersonDAO;

  @Service

  public class PersonServiceClass implements PersonService {

      @Autowired
      private PersonDAO personDAO;

      @Transactional  
      public void addContact(Person person) {
          personDAO.addContact(person);       
      }

      @Transactional  
      public List<Person> listPerson() {

          return personDAO.listPersons();
      }

      @Transactional
      public void removePerson(Integer id) {

          personDAO.removePerson(id);

      }

  }
  ```

I am getting this stacktrace error:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/mvctesting] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] with root cause
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:136)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:447)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:354)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.listPerson(Unknown Source)
        at es.landesoft.mvctesting.PersonController.getPersonJson(PersonController.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In addition, I would be glad if someone can give me some tips to help me organize the xml
config files. I am .NET developer and all this maven + xml configurations are something
new for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was changing the bean class in Datasource from:

```
<beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

to the spring Framework class:

```
 <beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use the DriverManagerDataSource in production because it isn't a connection pool (and hence no need for a close method as all connections are closed after usage!). You want to switch to something like C3P0 or Common-DBCP.

Comment: Eventhough it is a late, but making your service class as transactional by adding `Transactional` annotation to your service class may resolve it. I found out [here](http://techtopicsbyme.blogspot.com/2016/07/cannotcreatetransactionexception.html)

Comment: I am having the same issues. I changed the class to DriverManagerDataSource instead of BasicDataSource but no luck. Any more suggestion is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling you're using a version of commons-dbcp which is not compatible with the version of hibernate you're using... or that you have 2 versions of the commons-dbcp in your classpath.

#### Why?

Looking at the code from [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolingDataSource.java#PoolingDataSource), you can see that the method `getConnetion(String uname, String passwd)` only throws an exception (in the version in the link, the line is 127 rather than 136).

And from [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.java#BasicDataSource.getConnection%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29), you can see that it never calls `PoolingDataSource.getConnection(username, password)`

### solution

1. Check that you have only one copy of the classes above in your classpath
2. Try using commons-dbcp version 1.4

Comment: I updated my commons-jdcp version to 1.4 in maven and rebuild the project but still the same error ;(