# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, maven-3

I am new to Spring-MVC and Hibernate. Trying to create a test web application with **Spring-MVC(4.0.3)** , **Hibernate(4.3.5)** and using **MySQL** as back end.

There is no issue in connecting to the DB as I tried to fetch the data from the same db in a sample testJavaClass by using simple JDBC connection statements and I am able to fetch the records.

Error Log:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

root cause

 org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:515)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.listPersons(Unknown Source)
com.journeldev.spring.PersonController.listPersons(PersonController.java:29)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.raju.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                         <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
   </build>
  </project>
```

Project structure in Eclipse:

[image]

servlet-context.xml: (updated as per the answer by @Maciej Kowalski and I still see the same issue)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/rajuDB" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="raju" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="raju" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.journeldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journeldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journeldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- the transactional advice (what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.journeldev.spring" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>

 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>

 <!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
    of an operation defined by the FooService interface -->
 <aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="personServiceOperation" expression="execution(* com.journeldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="personServiceOperation"/>
 </aop:config>
 </beans:beans>
```

I have checked a lot of other threads on the internet and tried to change my `servlet-context.xml` file but nothing solved my issue.

Ex: tried to add extra parameters as per this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476782/could-not-open-hibernate-session-for-transaction-on-first-login) as below

```
    <beans:property name="initialSize" value="7"/>
    <beans:property name="maxActive" value="7"/>
    <beans:property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <beans:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <beans:property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="34000" />
    <beans:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
```

> Result: issue still remains same:

Ex 2: tried to change data source as per this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261404/springmvc-hibernate-cannotcreatetransactionexception-could-not-open-hiberna) as below

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/rajuDB" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="raju" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="raju" />
</beans:bean>
```

> result: issue remains same

Update as per comment from @James Jithin :19-Feb-2017

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection  conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/rajuDB", "raju", "raju");
        Statement state=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=state.executeQuery("select * from Person");

        if(rs!=null && rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("conn connected");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("not connected");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: I have added "Transactional" annotation to all the methods of PersonServiceImpl method which is again annotated with "@Service" at class level.

Comment: Suggested Reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please share your sample Java JDBC connection you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one heck of a mistake that I have done.! I apologize. There is no issue from the code and the xml configuration file.

Initial Plan: I have MySql setup in a virtual machine and running under port 3306. Plan is to run the application from tomcat instance that is running on my host machine. So, I have initiated port forwarding from host to VM with port 3307->3306 and a remote user 'raju' is created in MySQL to be able to connect from my host(tomcat running in host).

> Mistake: (because of some inexplicable reasons). I have decided to
> run the application in a separate tomcat instance that is running on
> my Virtual machine. In that case both tomcat and MySQL will be running
> on the same machine.
>
> 1: so there is no need do the PORT FORWARDING I should directly use
> the port 3306.
>
> 2: I have granted permission to the current remote user ( 'raju' ) to
> have the ability to connect locally as

```
grant all privileges on rajuDB.* to 'raju'@'localhost' identified by 'XXXX';
```

Final Result: Now I am able to fetch the details from database. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You should trust the error message:

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
> connection

Just because you can connect to the DB using a MySQL client application, doesn't mean that you can get to the DB over TCP. MySQL can connect over TCP port, or it could connect using pipe. Your MySQL client is probably connecting to the DB using *named pipe*.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

Comment: I have MySQL WorkBench setup a connection to the DB and it connecting thru Standard(TCP/IP) connection Method.

Comment: I hadn't put in the correct server address in my aws environment. This helped me figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your `personService` in the xml file, but you try to add transactional behaviour to it via annotations. Not 100% sure but i would stick to the xml definitions all the way and add transactional configuration there:

```
<!-- the transactional advice (what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
        of an operation defined by the FooService interface -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="personServiceOperation" expression="execution(* com.journeldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="personServiceOperation"/>
    </aop:config>
```

Also remove the @Transactional annotations from the service just in case.

Example is based on: [Spring Transaction Management Article](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html). It contains information on how to make your entire service layer transactional using xml configuration.

Comment: Or simply remove the `personService` bean definition from the XML.  He's already annotating it with `@Service` and has setup component scanning.  He shouldn't have to do anything else based on his configuration.

Comment: @Naros: I have removed "personService" bean from xml and try to run. I am getting an error. "personController" class is expecting "personService" to be autowired.

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski: I will try updating my code as per your comments and I will post my comments here.

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski: I have removed the "Transactional" annotation for PersonService and updated my 'servlet-context.xml' as above. I still see the same issue. Is there any changes needed at the MySql DB point.

Comment: @GhostRider `<context:component-scan base-package="com.journeldev.spring" />` basically tells spring to find any annotated `@Component` or its derivative classes and create them as beans.  That is why you shouldn't need them listed in the XML unless something else is wrong with your Spring setup.

Answer (score 0):

if you find , every bit of your connection code is correct , then you should check your Mysql Version that should compatible with Spring .
some of the older version is doesn't work with Spring latest version.

Comment: thank you. My problem got solved and I have shared the mistake that i have done. I would suggest you to add your reply as a comment rather than adding as an Answer as there is no potential solution given by you.